# Mediacodec decoder issues in MTK platform?

Tags: android-mediacodec

I'm working on a project of android video player, which required decode frame in realtime. I use the Mediacodec framework for decoding. I test my app in some device, and then I found that the Mediacodec decoder in MTK Platform will block serval frames in their own buffers, which leads the frame decode latency is much bigger and cannot achieve the . For example, the decoder would dequeueOutputBuffer a frame after I dequeueInputBuffer four frames. Is there any solutions to reduce the decode latency?